# Azure metric graph legend

Tags: azure, metrics, azure-application-insights

We recently saw a major downtime on one of our app service which is deployed on azure. After analyzing the logs through app insights we found something unknown in terms of what information a metric chart provides us.

[image: azure metrics request count]

As we can see there are the dotted line and solid line chart, what does that indicate at all? The time interval where we noticed this dotted line is actually when our service was not responding at all. Any clue on this how we can know what exactly went wrong at that time?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The dotted line in Azure Metrics Explorer indicates that there was no measured value (AKA “null”) between two aggregation points. For example, if in the time selector you picked “1 minute” time granularity but the metric was reported at 12:01, 12:02, 12:04, and 12:05 (note the minute gap between second and third data points), then the dotted line is shown between 12:02 and 12:04 and the solid line connects all other data points. Also, it may be useful to know that when there is no measured value, the dotted line drops down to zero when the metrics uses “Count” and “Sum” aggregation. When the aggregation is “Average”, “Minimum” or “Maximum” the dotted line simply connects two nearest known data points.

Vitaly Gorbenko

Program Manager at Microsoft Azure Monitor team

Comment: Is this documented anywhere? I couldn't find it in Microsoft docs, or in the Portal UI.

Comment: @jrr , it is documented here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/metrics-troubleshoot#chart-shows-dashed-line

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what Vitaly said above. Also when  you hover on the nearest point near the dotted line, you would see a "--" value in legend. Which is the way "no datapoint value" is represented.